# js - shorten the conditional statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Is there a way to make the conditional statement below shorter? There is a lot of repetition as you can see:

```
var searchArea = function() {
    // Search the area around the current position for hidden doors
    if(detectWall('left') == 2) {
        status.innerHTML = "Hidden Door to the left";
    } else if (detectWall('right') == 2) {
        status.innerHTML = "Hidden door to the right";
    } else if (detectWall('up') == 2) {
        status.innerHTML = "Hidden door above you";
    } else if (detectWall('down') == 2) {
        status.innerHTML = "Hidden door below you";
    } else if (detectWall('right') == 3 || detectWall('left') == 3 || detectWall('up') == 3 || detectWall('down') == 3) {
        status.innerHTML = "You are close to the fountain";
    }


}
```

And detectWall function for reference:

```
 var detectWall = function(dir) {
    // Detect walls from the array
    switch(dir) {
        case 'right':
            return mapArray[parseInt(player.y/20)][parseInt((player.x+20)/20)]
        case 'left':
            return mapArray[parseInt(player.y/20)][parseInt((player.x-20)/20)]
        case 'up':
            return mapArray[parseInt((player.y-20)/20)][parseInt(player.x/20)]
        case 'down':
            return mapArray[parseInt((player.y+20)/20)][parseInt(player.x/20)]
        default:
            return false
    }

}
```

Thank you

Comment: Yes there is, the people over at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), or even on the [golfing site](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) for funky solutions, will surely help you out.

Comment: But do be sure to check their [posting guidelines](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting.

Comment: OK. Thanks - didn't know of the code review section.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code contains no issues, and the question is more suited for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an idea to make that more generic:

```
var wallDetectorBase = [

    "left": { 
        incY: 0,
        incX: -20,
        hasWall: 2,
        msg: "Hidden Door to the left"
    },
    "right": {
        dir: "right",
        incY: 0,
        incX: 20,
        hasWall: 2,
        msg: "Hidden door to the right"
    },
```

now you couold iterate over the lefts and rights and combine the entire logic in one step:

```
for ( var n = 0; n < wallDetectorBase.length; n++ )
{
   if ( mapArray[parseInt((player.y + wallDetectorBase[n].incY ...]... == wallDetectorBase[n].hasWall )
   status.innerHTML = wallDetectorBase[n].msg;
```

Obviously the part `mapArray[parseInt((pl...` still needs some love, but that's only fiddling around with index math.